# Generate BarCode for UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, zxing, zbar-sdk

I want to generate a barcode on some UIImage or UIImageView.
Is it possible.I am using [This](https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator/downloads) for generating the barcode.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: did you mean you want to generate barcode for an Image ?

Comment: @Coder Thanks for the reply Yes.IS there any way?Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to use the URL of an online barcode generator as the source for a UIImage. For example:

```
NSString *barCodeValue = @"0123456789";
NSString *barCodeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=%@&style=197&type=C128B&width=200&height=100&xres=1&font=3", barCodeValue];
barCodeImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:barCodeURL]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you can give a try :

1) Convert `UIImage` into [Base64 String.](http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2010/03/14/Convert-image-tofrom-text-%28Base64%29.aspx)

2) Now, you use this string to generate barcode.

`[barcode setupQRCode:base64String];`

Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

if BarCode generated on UIView like component you can take screen shot of this view and get the image from this view hope this help you

```
-(UIImage *)getFinalImageAndBarCodeView:(UIView*)view{
////Create a new render context of the UIView size, and set a scale so that the full stage will render to it.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(view.bounds.size.width, view.bounds.size.height));
CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),1.0f,1.0f);

//Render the stage to the new context
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

// Get an image from the context
UIImage* viewImage=0;
viewImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

// Kill the render context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return viewImage;
```

}